# How to store T-SQL query output in new table with date of that day when query executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have to created a query which i have to run daily and attach the output in Excel.

But what I want is to schedule the query to run on a daily basis and the output will get stored  but I'm not able to do it completely.

For example I have this query

```
Select 
    @DateTo as [Execution Date], [Capacity],[Utilization],
    ([Utilization] / Capacity)*100 as [Utilization %] 
From 
    Occupancy
```

Result looks like this:

```
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| Execution Date | Capacity | Utilization  | Utilization % |
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 25-08-18       |    10000 |         9000 |            90 |
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now after scheduling it, I want my result to go in new table with every new date when query is executed.

```
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| Execution Date | Capacity | Utilization  | Utilization % |
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 25-08-18       |    10000 |         9000 | 90            |
| 26-08-18       |    10000 |         8000 | 80            |
| 27-08-18       |    10000 |         5000 | 50            |
| 28-08-18       |    10000 |         9230 | 92.3          |
+----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to know how I can modify this query to make it run daily and store results in a table with the date of that day.

```
Select 
    @DateTo as [Execution Date], [Capacity], [Utilization],
    ([Utilization]/Capacity)*100 as [Utilization %]
From 
    Occupancy
```

So far with browsing I get to know that I can schedule the query in SQL Server Agent.

Please help me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a new table and insert the result on each run to this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server Standard or Enterprise, you could use SQL Job to schedule a task. 
if you're using express edition, you'll need to use an alternative method of SQL Job.

for an alternative, you could use PowerShell script to handle the connection to SQL Server and executing the commands you want. [more about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

**PowerShell Script**

```
$SqlFile     = "X\SQLJob.sql"               # Replace X with File Path 
$OutputFile  = "X\SQLJob_Log.txt"           # Replace X with File Path 


## SET Connection
Set-Location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\X"             # Replace X with ServerName\InstanceName

## Do SQL Query
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $SqlFile | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile
```

Then, you need to save an SQL script so the PowerShell can execute it, and whenever its done, it'll write the results to a log file.

inside the SQL script, ensure that you specify the database name `USE DatabaseName` at the first line of file to map the script to the target it database. 
Example :

```
USE DatabaseName 

INSERT INTO SomeTable(ExecutionDate, Capacity, Utilization)
SELECT  
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
,   [Capacity]
,   ([Utilization] / Capacity)*100
From 
    Occupancy
```

Also, ensure that the windows login has the permissions to login to the database, execute, read and write. (or just give it sysadmin role). Otherwise, you'll need to

This is a general use script, you can modify it, expand it as you need.

Now, the only thing left is to use `Task Scheduler` in Windows, to schedule the powershell script so it can run on the schedule that you provide.

Comment: Thanks sir, I actually got right path , I have created new table first then inserting date as per given date now i will schedule it using Getdate()-1 which give actual closing .

Comment: One more thing now if query is getting executing twice then for same date getting results added to table . is there a way whenever my table finds data with same date one row get delete

Comment: If you only want the results of the most recent run for the day you could delete any records from the target table for the current day before inserting like this...

DELETE FROM SomeTable
WHERE ExecutionDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: @GauravMaggoo if you use windows scheduled tasks to run the script daily at 1PM. then, you'll always get a new unique date. But if you scheduled it in the same day twice, then you will need to remove the CAST so your GETDATE will be DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a query you can follow the link below.

https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-to-schedule-sql-query-to-run-in-microsoft-sql-server/

now in the add a Tsql which works like this

```
if not exists(select * from sysobjects where name = 'tbl_exection_archive')
Begin

 Select @DateTo as [Execution Date], [Capacity],[Utilization],([Utilization]/Capacity)*100 as [Utilization %] INTO tbl_exection_archive  
    from Occupancy where 1=2

End

insert into tbl_exection_archive 

 Select @DateTo as [Execution Date], [Capacity],[Utilization], 
([Utilization]/Capacity)*100 as [Utilization %] INTO tbl_exection_archive  
    from Occupancy where  @DateTo > (select max([Execution Date]) from 
tbl_exection_archive)
```

Comment: Sir just confirm why you have used this where 1=2 and  > (select max([Execution Date])

Comment: **tip** to make life simpler, don't include spaces or special characters in column names

Comment: @GauravMaggoo I have used "1=2" (false predicate) to create a table with copying structure of result set. I have used  "> (select max([Execution Date])" to get the rows which are not present in the table.

Comment: plase note that if you want to inser more records for a day then you will need to add more conditions.